# Balance the power of one resistor to other resistors

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, resistors, balancing

I have just a resistor of 10 ohms with 0.5 Watt configuration. The circuit does just need more power according to the input current. I calculated it and I have seen that the power raises up to 2 Watt. I could integrate just a resistor of 2 Watt into this circuit. The question goes to flexibility of resistors. Can I balance the power of 2 Watts reducing it to 0.5 Watt to each 10 ohm resistor, namely two in serial twice than these ones in parallel?

Edit:

The first circuit has an output at the end, not an input. :)

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you see, you can do that. You have built a 10 ohm 2 watt resistor out of four 10 ohm 0.5 watt resistors.

You can put any amount of any resistors in series or parallel or any combination of those, as long as they add up to 10 ohms and 2 watts if that is what you want.

It could be four 2.5 ohm resistors in series, or ten 1 ohm resistors.